# Website logs me in then immediately logs me out

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, login

I have an issue where I can log into a website that I have used all the time and then randomly it just stopped letting me stay logged in. You'd hit login, then immediately it will log me out. I tested logging in through a VPN, ran updates, tried different browsers, with no luck. Then tried logging in to this exact account on multiple computers and OS versions and they all worked.

So confused! I'm ready to about re-install windows!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The only reason you wouldn’t have been able to submit an answer is if it was protected. Likewise, this question, doesn’t appear to be an actual question just you notifying us that you couldn’t submit an answer to a question

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) also
[How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How can I help the next person by offering an answer to the issue that I have? Is there a section where I can just give answers? ...or wait should I ask my question then answer with my solution immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that the time on my computer was behind by 3 minutes. And I just had to set Time and Time Zone to change automatically. Crazy how something so simple can cause so much trouble. I've had time related issues with local domain servers, but never thought it could cause issues with a website like this...

Anyways, hope this helps someone!

Comment: That can cause SSH and SFTP to fail, as well, though I thought the time difference allowed was ~15 minutes.